# CSS Generator for Multi-Browser Support

Tags: css, code-generation

I know that there are several very similarly-related questions on this website, however after reviewing the play, I believe this question is unique in its own right. If someone can find and provide evidence of an exact dupe of my question, I will withdraw it myself (so please just don't **downvote** this!).

I am a Java developer, not a web developer. But, as is the case in so many families where there is one person who becomes the designated family "*computer guy*", my Java development skills have been mistaken for web development skills, and I somehow got roped into building a website for my parents to help them sell their house.

So, like any web development newbie, I wrote the HTML/CSS myself (by hand, sans editor like DW or Expression, etc.) and tested it against FireFox 3.x. All looked great, and we deployed/launched.

Now we're getting negative feedback from everyone and their dog stating that the site isn't rendering properly in other browsers, browser versions, or on FireFox installations running on different operating systems. Similarly, the site is apparently a total mess when being viewed through a smart phone or tablet device.

Now I *could* dive in and write a whole bunch of messy, nasty, painstakingly-tedious edits to my CSS rules, that basically say: *do X when browser is Y*, etc. But I am hoping that out there is a tool that can put all my fears to rest.

What I'm looking for is a tool that could take my valid CSS files, and use them to generate CSS rules that will be compatible with a high percentage of all common browsers/versions.

Alternatively, if I have to re-write my CSS from scratch, it would be nice to have a tool that allows me to *write/design once, deploy many*, so that I only have to focus on the design of a single CSS file, but the code that gets generated is multi-browser compatible.

It sounds like DreamWeaver **kind of** does this, but you have to choose from one of 16 pre-existing templates.

My wife is a graphic designer, and made the website pretty sweet (not cookie cutter). It was a nightmare trying to figure out what CSS rules to use to implement her design. So any tool that forces you to choose between templates is not an option.

Is there any hope for me, or do I banish myself from my family in shame right now?

Comment: Can you share the website's location and/or source code and/or screenshots?

Comment: also you accepted my answer just figured that part was missing (SO won't display the meta tag line for some reason - please check the answer again - maybe that would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css is a mess, no way to automatically doing it right. saying that I would say there are tools that would walk with you the proper way.
1. use the meta tag:

> http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" (encpsulate as a meta tag - SO won't display if I wrote it as a valid tag)

to force IE to render with it's most modern engine, that would solve some problems.

2.begin your css with [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) - that would eliminate some of the cross browser problems - because it resets your css (better and more modern the reset.css)

1. I'll second the GWT if you come from the java dev world. although It's a framework to learn with it's own quirks. another possible web framework is Grails - a nice java/groovy port of the mighty Ror.
2. Less or Scss won't automatically solve your basic problem - which is browser compatibily - but are a better and simpler way to write css
3. remember that most css3 properties aren't support equally in all browsers (and in IE almost not supported) - use them only with graceful downgrade option with supported js or css -when [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) js library can give you pretty good property support detection for various browsers
4. don't go dreamweaver - it produces terrible code
5. use [csslint](http://csslint.net/) to check for valid css and common css pitfalls
6. If you must use cutting edge web rendering with html5+css3 elements you should look into chrome frame -that would enable older browser better support of your site - although I believe this may be an overkill for a simple sell-my-house kind of site.
7. use a css framework to prototype- it would give you better css, good basics and resets and good boilerplate - maybe bootstrap or something similiar (didn't try most of them but the internet is crowded with those.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm looking for is a tool that could take my valid CSS files, and
>   use them to generate CSS rules that will be compatible with a high
>   percentage of all common browsers/versions.

Unfortunately there's no such a tool and you have to debug and test your website for cross-browser compatibility manually. The best way i've found for cross-browser testing it to install and test different versions of browsers in several virtual machines.

You will also find the following helpful:

[Modernizr](http://Modernizr.com)

[Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out modernizr.  http://www.modernizr.com/docs/

You want to get into the position of checking for features and not browsers.

Here's an excellent site to check your site with alternative browsers:

http://www.browserstack.com/

Answer (score 0):

Less (http://lesscss.org/) will help you with a lot of CSS3 functions.

However, good CSS code simply works on all browsers. There are some CSS concepts that must always be avoided as much as possible (absolute positioning, excessive floats, using the wrong elements for a task, etc) and your code will work better.

In the many years I have programmed I only needed browser-specific code in the first two years. Then I grew up and learned which CSS code not to use and when it was possible to use them. It has been my experience that properly written CSS code works on all browsers, and if it doesn't it will at least get the basic concepts right (eg. a few pixels may be wrong or some effects, but the site still works well).

Answer (score 0):

Several things come to mind that may help your case:

- Forget about IE6, that one will give you trouble no matter how much effort you put into the site.
- Make sure you have a good doctype (html5 or xhtml would be good).
- Try out [html5 reset](http://html5reset.org/), it tries to make sure all browsers behave the same.
- The aforementioned reset also includes [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/) to bring older browsers up to speed

Finally: accept (some even say "embrace") that different browsers render things slightly different. Getting every pixel exactly the same in each browser will be near impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to put this into the world, but it sounds like you need Adobe Muse.

There is no equal to a good developer who will write clean cross browser code, but if you just want to get the site done check out the beta: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/muse/